# What is the correct regex for this exercise in python?

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercise on python but my regex is wrong I hope someone can help me, the exercise is this:

Fill in the code to check if the text passed looks like a standard sentence,
meaning that it starts with an uppercase letter, followed by at least some lowercase
letters or a space, and ends with a period, question mark, or exclamation point

```
import re

def check_sentence(text):       
   result = re.search(r"^[A-Z]+[a-z]+[\s]+[a-z]+[\.!\?]$", text)
   return result != None

print(check_sentence("Is this is a sentence?")) # True
print(check_sentence("is this is a sentence?")) # False
print(check_sentence("Hello")) # False
print(check_sentence("1-2-3-GO!")) # False
print(check_sentence("A star is born.")) # True
```

Comment: You can test your regex using https://regex101.com/

Comment: The exercise is not well defined. Should two or more consecutive spaces be allowed? Should a space directly before a punctuation be allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current regex doesn't work because it tries to look for

`^[A-Z]+[a-z]+[\s]+[a-z]+[\.!\?]$`: https://regex101.com/r/b96zXT/2

- `^[A-Z]+`: One or more capital letters at the start of the string
- `[a-z]+`: One or more small letters after the capital letters
- `[\s]+`: One or more whitespaces after the small letters
- `[a-z]+`: One or more small letters after the spaces
- `[\.!\?]+$`: One or more of the punctuations (`.`, `!`, or `?`) after the second run of small letters, and then the string ends.

What you actually want to do:

`^[A-Z][A-Za-z\s]+[\.!\?]$` https://regex101.com/r/r3CAdh/2

- `^[A-Z]`: **Exactly one** capital letter at the start of the string
- `[A-Za-z\s]+`: One or more capital letters / small letters / spaces
- `[\.!\?]$`: One punctuation mark at the end of the string

Comment: `^[A-Z][A-Za-z\s]+[\.!\?]$` will not work for the case `Oh!`. `^[A-Z][A-Za-z\s]*[\.!\?]$`  will work on such sentences as well.

Comment: @PankajChandravanshi the first regex works for `"Oh!"` It doesn't work for single-letter sentences (`"O!"`), because the `+` on the second character class requires one or more characters after the first uppercase character.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following regex forbidding consecutive spaces and spaces directly before punctuations

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]*(\s[a-z]+)*[\.!\?]$/
```

Explanation

- `^` must start at the beginning of the input string
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` the first word must start with a capital letter, followed by an arbitrary number of lowercase letters
- `(\s[a-z]+)*` after the first word, there can be an arbitrary number of additional words (also zero). Each word must be preceded by one white space (you can also use just a space instead of `\s` to only allow space but not for instance tab) and consist of at least one lowercase letter
- `[\.!\?]$` the punctuation must be at the end of the input string.

This will for instance allow

```
This is a valid sentence.
```

But forbid something like

```
This is not valid !
This  is not valid either!
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
    import re
    def check_sentence(text):
      result = re.search(r"^[A-Z][A-Za-z\s]*[\.\?!]$", text)
      return result != None

    print(check_sentence("Is this is a sentence?")) # True
    print(check_sentence("is this is a sentence?")) # False
    print(check_sentence("Hello")) # False
    print(check_sentence("1-2-3-GO!")) # False
    print(check_sentence("A star is born.")) # True
```

Comment: at least explain what your regex has done. It's like an alien language in sci-fi movies for some people.

Answer (score 0):

From the question is ask

- It starts with an **uppercase letter**, so then we use `^[A-Z]`.
- Followed by **at least some lowercase letter or space**, for that we can use `[a-z\s]+`.
- and ends with **a period, question mark, or exclamation point**. so we can use `[\.\?!]$`. the `\` before `.` and `?` is called "Escape character", it uses for escaping the `.` and `?` since both of it was part of regular expression action.

there you go, the answer to your question is `result = re.search(r"^[A-Z][a-z\s]+[\.\?!]$", text)`.

Comment: * in regex means 0 or more. not "at least some" (more than 1) meaning your regex doesn't actually satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Thanks you for the insight, i'll fix it. I hope the update one is better.

Answer (score -1):

try this it will work

```
re.search(r"^[A-Z]+[a-z\s]*[\.!\?]$", text)
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [the answer from derpirscher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64126736/3025856) and [the accepted answer from Pranav Hosangadi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64126368/3025856) for best practices on how to answer regular expression questions. RegEx syntax can be really intimidating to people, and just offering code doesn't help them understand how to solve similar problems in the future. Consider editing your answer to explain what each segment does, and also why this approach might be preferred over the existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

This also works btw.

```
 re.search(r"^[A-Z][a-z\s].*[.?!]$", text)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
re.search(r"^[A-Z][a-z ]+[.?!]$", text)
```

Comment: if you explain a bit then the quality of your answer goes up and prevents vastly down-voting/close-voting behavior. End of Review.

Answer (score -2):

For the condition that you have set this reg ex should work.

```
re.search(r"^[A-Z][a-z ]*[?.!]$", text)
```